# JSF beans with generics

Tags: spring, jsf

I'm trying to understand previously written code.

Here are class defined:

```
public abstract class BaseModel{....}


public abstract class ExtendedModel<T extends BaseModel>{....}


public class MyViewBean extends BaseModel{...}

public class MyController extends ExtendedModel<MyViewBean > {....}
```

In configs:

```
<bean name="MyViewBean" id="myViewBean" scope="request" class="com.bean.MyViewBean"/>

<bean name="MyController" id="myController" scope="session" 
        class="com.controller.MyController" init-method="init">
    The property list goes here (in this list there is no myViewBean reference).
</bean>
```

In JSF page:

```
<rich:dataTable id="myList" value="#{myController}" var="myViewBean"...>
       <rich:column>
               <h:outputText value="#{myViewBean.myproperty}" />
       </rich:column>
</rich:datatable>
```

I need to make some changes in datatable, but I cann't understand what is exactly `var="myViewBean"` in  and `value="#{myViewBean.myproperty}"` within `<rich:column>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `var="myViewBean"` just sets the EL variable name of the currently iterated object, so that you can access it by `#{myViewBean}` in the EL scope inside the component. It effects basically the same as following in plain Java:

```
for (MyViewBean myViewBean : myController) {
    System.out.println(myViewBean.getMyproperty());
}
```

The `myViewBean` variable is not available outside the loop.

This has **nothing** to do with generics. Even more, [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) is in Java just a compile time aid and they are erased after compilation.